# how to animate view from bottom to top in iOS using CATransform3D

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, catransform3d

I am animating UIView to have a feeling of book's page effect

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *insideView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *pageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *backPageView;
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGRect cardFrame;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

    //create frame for 2 test views
    CGFloat size = 200.0;
    _cardFrame = CGRectMake([[self view] center].x - size / 2, [[self view] center].y - size / 2 , size, size);

    //lower view
    _insideView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: _cardFrame];
    [_insideView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    //upper view
    _pageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_cardFrame];
    [_pageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    //upper view back side
    _backPageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_cardFrame];
    [_backPageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    [[self view] addSubview:_insideView];
    [[self view] addSubview:_pageView];
    [[self view] insertSubview:_backPageView belowSubview:_pageView];

    //get layer of upper view and set needed property
    CALayer *viewLayer = [_pageView layer];
    CALayer *viewBackLayer = [_backPageView layer];

    [viewLayer setAnchorPoint:(CGPoint){0.0 , 0.5}];
    [viewLayer setFrame:_cardFrame];
    [viewLayer setDoubleSided:NO];
    [viewBackLayer setAnchorPoint:(CGPoint){0.0 , 0.5}];
    [viewBackLayer setFrame:_cardFrame];

    //create perspective
    CATransform3D mt = CATransform3DIdentity;
    mt.m34 = 1.0/-500.;

    //create rotation
    CATransform3D open = CATransform3DMakeRotation(3 * M_PI_4,0,-1, 0);

    //create result transform
    CATransform3D openTransform = CATransform3DConcat(open, mt);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
     {
         //close animation
         [viewLayer setTransform:openTransform];
         [viewBackLayer setTransform:openTransform];
     } completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
          {
              //close animation
              [viewLayer setTransform:CATransform3DIdentity];
              [viewBackLayer setTransform:CATransform3DIdentity];
          }];
     }];
}
```

But i want the UIView to animate from bottom to top,this code do animate but from left to right like book's page.
Please help!!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

//create frame for 2 test views
CGFloat size = 200.0;
_cardFrame = CGRectMake([[self view] center].x - size / 2, [[self view] center].y - size / 2 , size, size);

//lower view
_insideView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: _cardFrame];
[_insideView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

//upper view
_pageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_cardFrame];
[_pageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

//upper view back side
_backPageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_cardFrame];
[_backPageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[[self view] addSubview:_insideView];
[[self view] addSubview:_pageView];
[[self view] insertSubview:_backPageView belowSubview:_pageView];

//get layer of upper view and set needed property
CALayer *viewLayer = [_pageView layer];
CALayer *viewBackLayer = [_backPageView layer];

// need to change the anchor point to center of top edge. 
// that is the point in which you need to rotate.
[viewLayer setAnchorPoint:(CGPoint){0.5 , 0.0}];
[viewLayer setFrame:_cardFrame];
[viewLayer setDoubleSided:NO];
[viewBackLayer setAnchorPoint:(CGPoint){0.5 , 0.0}];
[viewBackLayer setFrame:_cardFrame];

//create perspective
CATransform3D mt = CATransform3DIdentity;
mt.m34 = 1.0/-500.;

//need to rotate in X axis. so changed arguments.
CATransform3D open = CATransform3DMakeRotation(3 * M_PI_4,1,0, 0);

//create result transform
CATransform3D openTransform = CATransform3DConcat(open, mt);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
 {
     //close animation
     [viewLayer setTransform:openTransform];
     [viewBackLayer setTransform:openTransform];
 } completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
      {
          //close animation
          [viewLayer setTransform:CATransform3DIdentity];
          [viewBackLayer setTransform:CATransform3DIdentity];
      }];
 }];
}
```

Comment: Most peoples heads don't have built in diff algorithms. Please explain what changes you've made to the OP's code.

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
//create frame for 2 test views
CGFloat size = 200.0;
_cardFrame = CGRectMake([[self view] center].x - size / 2, [[self view] center].y - size / 2 , size, size);

//lower view
_insideView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: _cardFrame];
[_insideView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

//upper view
_pageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_cardFrame];
[_pageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

//upper view back side
_backPageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_cardFrame];
[_backPageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[[self view] addSubview:_insideView];
[[self view] addSubview:_pageView];
[[self view] insertSubview:_backPageView belowSubview:_pageView];

//get layer of upper view and set needed property
CALayer *viewLayer = [_pageView layer];
CALayer *viewBackLayer = [_backPageView layer];

[viewLayer setAnchorPoint:(CGPoint){0.5 , 0.0}];
[viewLayer setFrame:_cardFrame];
[viewLayer setDoubleSided:NO];
[viewBackLayer setAnchorPoint:(CGPoint){0.5 , 0.0}];
[viewBackLayer setFrame:_cardFrame];

//create perspective
CATransform3D mt = CATransform3DIdentity;
mt.m34 = 1.0/-500.;

//create rotation
CATransform3D open = CATransform3DMakeRotation(3 * M_PI_4,1,0,0);

//create result transform
CATransform3D openTransform = CATransform3DConcat(open, mt);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
 {
     //close animation
     [viewLayer setTransform:openTransform];
     [viewBackLayer setTransform:openTransform];
 } completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
      {
          //close animation
          [viewLayer setTransform:CATransform3DIdentity];
          [viewBackLayer setTransform:CATransform3DIdentity];
      }];
 }];
```

Comment: Most peoples heads don't have built in diff algorithms. Please explain what changes you've made to the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

The two key parts in that page flip is the rotation transform and the anchor point. If you are unfamiliar with this then I suggest that you look at the documentation to see how they work, I will only give a brief explanation.

### Rotation transform

You can see that `CATransform3DMakeRotation` takes 4 arguments, the first is the angle of the rotation and the next three are the axis of the rotation. You are rotating around (0,-1, 0) which is the y axis (vertical on the screen). To instead cause a rotation around the horizontal axis (x) you should change the last 3 arguments to `1, 0, 0` (or maybe `-1`, I can't seem to remember that on the top of my head).

```
CATransform3D open = CATransform3DMakeRotation(3.0*M_PI_4, // angle 
                                               1, 0, 0);   // axis
```

### Anchor point

The anchor point specifies how the layer is drawn relative to its position. Both x and y in the anchor point range from 0 to 1 so (0.5, 0.5) is in the center of the layer, no matter the size. In your case the anchor point is (0.0, 0.5) meaning center left edge. You should probably change that to (0.5, 0.0) center top edge or (0.5, 1.0) center bottom edge depending on where you want the anchor point to be for your page flip.

```
viewLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0); // center top edge
```

Answer (score 0):

set Uiview Frame in view did Load then set on your event button clicked. view animaate Bottom to top

```
CGRect optionsFrame = AddNOTEview.frame;

optionsFrame.origin.y=300;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.50];

AddNOTEview.frame = optionsFrame;

 [self.view addSubview:AddNOTEview];
```

Comment: want to do this with catransform3d